# Here lies - so telling lies here?

Tags: phrases

Sorry for my low level question, I am not native... I am thinking of a phrase "here lies Joe" which does not mean something like "Joe is telling lies here". I wonder why is it so obvious that this means Joe rests in peace here...

Comment: Why would you want to say "Joe is telling lies in this place"? Especially if Joe was dead, or not there.

Comment: My wife (who is not native also) asked me that question, and I cannot answer other that something like that. Now I am trying to find a better answer :) Do you have one? Or is it as simple as it? Might means "telling lies" but ... not!

Comment: I notice you say *why is it so obvious that this means Joe **rests in peace here*** without giving it a second thought. But that's an extremely "non-obvious" idiomatic expression itself. People who are *dead* can't actually "rest" at all, and the idea that dead people are "in peace" is just a social convention that doesn't really make much sense. So whatever  rationalization you apply to explain / justify using *that* construction should work just as well for explaining *Here lies John.*

Comment: You could make a bad pun out of this (essentially [antanaclasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antanaclasis)): "Here lies Joe, a devoted husband and father--but over there he tells the truth."

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that "Here lies..." is a **fixed phrase,** actually coming from the Latin *Hic jacet...* found on gravestones (and common up to say the 1700s, when Latin inscriptions began to be replaced by English).

When talking about telling untruths, one might say "Joe is lying here," and it's the context which distinguishes which meaning of *lying* — and, indeed, *here* — is meant. [*Lying here* might mean "resting in this location", or "telling untruths in this present situation."]

Answer (score 4):

*Here lies* is a fixed expression. It is a  calque (direct, word-for-word translation) of the Latin *hic jacet*. As such, it happens also to be word-for-word equivalent to the French *ci-gît*.

Comment: Ha! Great minds and all that.

Comment: 'Here sits Joe', 'There stands Joe', while by no means ungrammatical, are dated and/or literary, and would not be used in conversation. But 'Here lies X' is carved in stone.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth And there goes the neighborhood. (Speaking of [tombstones](https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/173/386023351_ae7b0cf260_b.jpg).)